# Check if array of URLS exist without importing external npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm iterating over a list of URL and i want to check each time if the url exists or not without having to download the entirety of the page and if possible without importing any external npm package.Is there any way i can do that ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: use `HEAD` as a request method in  [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: I tried using request and http.get but it s taking too long I just need to check if the url exists or not